# Embedding resource using inline assembly

Tags: gcc, global-variables, inline-assembly

I tried to use this trick together to embed a resource into an executable file:

```
#define INCLUDE_BINARY(identifier,filename) \
asm("\t.data\n" \
    "\t.local " #identifier "_begin\n" \
    "\t.type " #identifier "_begin, @object\n" \
    "\t.align 16\n" \
     #identifier "_begin:\n" \
    "\t.incbin \"" filename "\"\n\n" \
    \
    "\t.local " #identifier "_end\n" \
    "\t.type " #identifier "_end, @object\n" \
    "\t.align 1\n" \
    #identifier "_end:\n" \
    "\t.byte 0\n"); \
\    
extern uint8_t identifier##_begin[];\
extern const uint8_t identifier##_end[]
```

So that

```
#include <herbs/include_binary/include_binary.h>
#include <herbs/main/main.h>
#include <cstdio>

INCLUDE_BINARY(source,__FILE__);

int MAIN(int argc,charsys_t* argv[])
    {
    const uint8_t* begin=source_begin;
    while(begin!=source_end)
        {
        putchar(*begin);
        ++begin;
        }
    return 0;
    }
```

will print itself. It works fine until I enable debug symbol generation. Then I get errors:

```
/tmp/ccCfX7kc.s:103: Error: can't resolve `.data' {.data section} - `.Ltext0' {.text section}
```

I guess the reason of failure is that `-g` adds stuff at the beginning of file:

```
    .text
.Ltext0:
```

Is there a way to add global symbols using inline assembly that does not interfere with debugging? Is asm undefined outside a function body?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to restore the section back to `.text` at the end of the inline asm. You could use `.pushsection` and `.popsection` todo so.

Comment: Added .text at the end of the macro for `_WIN32` for now.